# Custom regular expression for grok

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

My question is about grok filter in logstash. For logstash filter I need to parse a log file . Sample log statement below

> 2017-07-31 09:01:53,135 - INFO 
>   [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@617] -
>   Established session 0x15d964d654646f4 with negotiated timeout 5000 for
>   client /10.191.202.89:56232

I want to parse statement between [] using regular expression but did not get any success ? From above line

1. *QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181* should be mapped to thread id .
2. *ZooKeeperServer* should be mapped to class name
3. *617* should be mapped with line number

Can someone help me with the regular expression for this ?

Comment: Can you add what you already tried?

Comment: Would you post your entire conf file so I can see how exactly all of this is suppose to be done? I've been stuck all day trying to figure out how to make a custom regular expression work and even in the kibana debugger I cannot get it right. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\[(?<threadid>\w+[^/]*/[\d:]+):(?<classname>[^\]@]+)@(?<linenumber>\d+)\]
```

**Details**

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `(?<threadid>\w+[^/]*/[\d:]+)` - Group "threadid": 1+ word chars, then 0+ chars other than `/`, `/` and then 1 or more digits or `:` (note that you may adjust this pattern as you see fit, e.g. it can also be written as `(?<threadid>.*?[\d:]+)` but it won't be that safe)
- `:` - a colon
- `(?<classname>[^\]@]+)` - Group "classname": 1 or more chars other than `]` and `@`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?<linenumber>\d+)` - Group "linenumber": 1 or more digits
- `\]` - a literal `]`.

Online test results at [grokdebug.herokuapp.com](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I do not want to hard code QuorumPeer in regex. It will not work in case of below statement  :  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@178]